# Get From-Header from MIME-Mail using re.findall() fails

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract email-addresses using the `re.findall()` function. I am using a `for`-loop to read the text-file line by line, yet the output is only an empty list. I can use `findall()` perfectly for a single line, yet not while reading a text file line by line.

```
from re import *
fname = input('enter file name\n:')  
fhand = open(fname)
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = findall('^From (\S+@\S+)', line)
    print(x)
```

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: Try removing the `^` or adding the [`MULTILINE` flag](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

Comment: `^` means to start the match at the start of the line. You'll have a maximum of 1 address in each line because only one can be at the start. Do you expect this pattern to be repeated in a single line? Consider printing the lines as you process them. Take a few lines you think should match and add them to this question so we can take a crack at it.

Comment: Let's clarify: if you remove the `for` loop and use `print(findall(r'\S+@\S+\.\S+', fhand.read()))`, does it show expected matches?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to read one line at a time. You can apply the `findall()` function to the whole file.

```
from re import findall
fname = input('filename> ')

with open(fname,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

#data = ['from foobarbaz@gmail.com','From FooBar_Baz@hotmail.com.es','...']

mails = findall('(?i)from\s+\S+@\S+\.\S+(?:\.\S+)?',data)
for mail in mails: print(mail)
```